# Flyway : custom validation on each migration

Tags: flyway

is it possible to ask flyway to run a custom sql script after each scripts runned during a migration?
The custom script would allow us to validate our sql standards.

We don't want to manually add the content of our validation script in each update script.

Maybe the flyway callback could help, nut I don't understand how it works...

If you have an idea, you're welcome!
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, an callback is the right approach. In 3.0 you still have to implement them in Java. We're looking at simplifying them for 3.1.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, do you know some tuto on the Flyway callback?
And is it possible to trigger the migration failure from the callback?
In my case I thought to call "afterEachMigrate" function and test here if the standard are respected.
The question here is: does "afterEachMigrate" is part of the update script transaction, in order to rollback migration on validation failure.

Comment: I just notice that our flyway version is 2.3.1, so I wonder if the callbacks are available with it, or if we'll have to update.